# Rapidjson Document

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I am trying to create a json document using rapidjson but I don't know how I can replicate part of the following document, in particular the nested object starting with "allocations", for the others elements I do

```
Value valObjectString(kStringType);
valObjectString.SetString("string");
doc.AddMember("string", valObjectString, doc.GetAllocator());
```

But what about "allocation" and "url" ?

```
{
  "string1": "string",
  "string2": "string",
  "string3": "string",
  "string4": "string",
  "string5": "string",
  "allocations": [
    {
      "allocation": "string",
      "url": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you can do like this

```
Value valObjectString(kStringType);
valObjectString.SetString("string");
doc.AddMember("string", valObjectString, doc.GetAllocator());

Value array(kArrayType);
Value tmp;
tmp.SetObject();
tmp.AddMember("allocation", "string", doc.GetAllocator());
tmp.AddMember("url", "string", doc.GetAllocator());
array.PushBack(tmp, doc.GetAllocator());
doc.AddMember("allocations", array, doc.GetAllocator());
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to create the wanted JSON Document would be to use the `"rapidjson/writer.h"` include.

You need to use `writer.Key()` to create the key of the object and name it. Then, you can use `writer.String()` to set the value of the key.

(Here I used `.String()`, but you can use any type that is supported by RapidJson.)

Also, you can easily tell the writer when to Start and End objects and arrays with `writer.StartObject()`, `writer.StartArray()`, `writer.EndObject()` and `writer.EndArray()` commands.

```
Document yourJsonDoc;

StringBuffer s;
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(s);

writer.StartObject();
writer.Key("string1");
writer.String("string");
writer.Key("string2");
writer.String("string");
writer.Key("string3");
writer.String("string");
writer.Key("string4");
writer.String("string");
writer.Key("string5");
writer.String("string");
writer.Key("allocations");
writer.StartArray();
writer.StartObject();
writer.Key("allocations");
writer.String("string");
writer.Key("url");
writer.String("string");
writer.EndObject();
writer.EndArray();
writer.EndObject();

yourJsonDoc.Parse(s.GetString().c_str());
```

And so on if you'd like to add additional objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you need to create an array containing allocation and url and you need to put this array inside allocations :

```
rapidjson::Value myArray(rapidjson::kArrayType);

doc.AddMember("allocations", myArray, doc.getAllocator);
```